# change style css for class

Tags: javascript, html, css

here is a part of my code:
The Idea is to change e.g. the backgroundcolor of both fields with the class 'navicon' like you can see in the function fu() but it did not work and not work in this or that way. Changing the color about the id is no problem, but i dont want to give any button a specific id. Any Idea where my mistake and missunderstanding is? Thx!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
<!        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navside.css" type="text/css">
          <style>
.navside {
    list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    }

.navside a {
    float: center;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    }

.navside a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>    
function fun(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor="red";

    function fu(){ 
        var all = document.getElementsByClassName('navicon');
        for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){
            all[i].style.backgroundColor='red';
        }
    }
}
</script>

<div class="navside">
    <a class="navicon" id="demo" href="#bla" onclick="fun()" >Text1</a><br>
    <a class="navicon"  href="#blubb" onclick="fu()">Text2</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LyQwmQ

Comment: line 5, you shouldn't have `<!` there.

Comment: function fun() missing and ending '}'

Comment: *"...but it did not work"* **Ok, so the `background-color` doesn't change** *"and not work in this"* **What is "this"?** *"or that way."*  **What "way"?**

Comment: @vabii The ending `}` is right above `</script>`. It's easier to see since I fixed the indentation.

Comment: @fuzzy Check my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you put the definition of `fu()` inside `fun()`, so it's not callable from the global scope. There doesn't seem to be any need for it to be a local function, I guess this was just a mistake. Define them both globally.

```
function fun(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor="red";
}

function fu(){ 
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName('navicon');
    for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){
        all[i].style.backgroundColor='red';
    }
}
```

You should have gotten a clue about this problem from the error message in the Javascript console saying that the function `fu` doesn't exist.

Comment: Omfg ... i am coding Fortran and C for so many years ant then i make such a &%§?#*& mistake .......me->corner->cry->cry very loud xDDD

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a function that does not exist

This is correct:

*get the length inside lopp is bad practice*

```
function fun(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
function fu(){ 
    var all = document.getElementsByClassName('navicon'),
        len = all.length,
        i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i+=1){
        all[i].style.backgroundColor='red';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, i have seen, such a damn stupid mistake xD Coding Fortran and C for years and then such an error, omfg, shame on me xD. Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

```
function fun(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

It can be achieved without the for loop using `querySelectorAll`.

```
function fu(){ 
    document.querySelectorAll('.navicon')
        .forEach((el) => { el.style.backgroundColor='red' });

}
```

Comment: Yay, it worked that way i want it too, thx.But in case i would have e.g. 100 of those, is there a way to edit a single one out of a vector like el[24] .... you know?